# Remove viewcontroller & move to next view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, model-view-controller

Hi i have been working on an iOS app.What i am doing is navigating among diffrent view controllers. But the problem is i want finish the current view controller from emoery and then move to the next view controller.

I am using `[self.view removeFromSuperview]; for finishing the cureent view & using

```
 self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
    [self presentViewController:self.loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

for moving to next view controller but the thing is i am not able to remove it from memory.

Please tell me how can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create a container view controller which manages your view controllers. For example, in viewDidLoad: of container controller you add current controller:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.currentViewController];
[self.currentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubView:self.currentViewController.view];
//here set up currentViewController view's frame or constraints if needed
```

When you need to open login controller, do this:

```
[self addChildViewController:loginViewController];
[self.loginViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubView:loginViewController.view];
//here set up loginViewController view's frame or constraints if needed

//then remove current view controller
[self.currentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
[self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Do you want to use navigation controller to push new controller? As I understand you don't use it now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from superview will remove it from the current view, but OS won't remove it until he needs to (this is topic for more explanation, let's say it won't remove it asap).

If you want something deleted just call it nil:

> self.view = nil;

This will make the pointer to nil, so view won't be there any more. (the view really will be somewhere but you won't have access to it)

Comment: if write like this 

[self.view removefromsuperview]

self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
    [self presentViewController:self.loginView animated:NO completion:nil];

Then it says that the you are trying to remove a view controller which not in view hierarchy

Comment: @TarunSharma before removing a view, you need first to present a new* one

Answer (score 0):

If you try to remove not only UIView but the whole UIViewController from a navigation controller stack use this snippet

```
NSMutableArray *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[stack removeObject:yourController];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = stack;
```

Be aware of using this only when you've already pass to the next controller view.

**UPD:**

Oh, now I see what you are trying to do. And I can't figure out, why you're trying to step your controllers this way (modally). I think you should use UINavigationController with navigation segues defined directly from your storyboard. Look [at this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) article where apple purely explains what navigation is. [That article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) is about modal views

Comment: should i write it before or after moving to next view controller

Comment: What is navigation array

Answer (score 0):

I am revising your code

```
self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
[self presentViewController:self.loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

What you are doing here is presenting your login viewcontroller.

self: This is the instance of the viewcontroller you are currently working on. So how could you remove self from memory. (Not Possible)

You can approach alternate ways.

For example: 1. Changing root view controller

2. Pop to root view controller and then Push Login View controller.

Comment: can you give some piece of code please as an sample